# How to dynamically change mkdir dirrectory names in build.xml file

Tags: apex, api, integration, ant

Consider below example build.xml file. How do i dynamically set mkdir dir="directory" name (bolded part in the example build.xml content). Example it should change name everytime it runs and not overwrite existing directory. Example retrieveUnpackaged1, retrieveUnpackaged2, retrieveUnpackaged3 and so on

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
<property environment="env"/>

<condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
<condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
<condition property="sf.sessionId" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.sessionId"/> </not> </condition>

<target name="retrieveUnpackaged">
  **<mkdir dir="retrieveUnpackaged"/>**
  <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged" unpackaged="unpackaged/package.xml"/>
</target>
```

.......

Thanks
Amrut

Comment: This is a question that would be better asked on [so]. If this were any other Ant task that wasn't related to Salesforce, the answer would be the same, so you'll get a better response if you ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, using a timestamp:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY" pattern="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
</tstamp>
<mkdir dir="retrieveUnpackaged-${TODAY}"/>
```